# Facebook Permissions Dialog in Page

Tags: facebook, permissions, authorization

I've created an app that works fine, however if the user has not authorized my app yet, they have to do the following (assuming they are in facebook AND logged in) -

1. go to my app
2. click login/authorize
3. popup with facebook permissions opens
4. accept in the popup

However I noticed with Zynga games like Mafia Wars 1/2, Farmville etc, when you go to the app, if it hasn't been authorized, it takes you straight to the permissions which is in a PAGE and not a popup, thereby eliminating one step.  Also, the permissions dialog is full width, there is not app sidebar.

Does anyone know how I can duplicate this flow?  It would be much easier to have users authorize within a facebook page rather than through a popup.  How can I get permissions inside the page?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Once user visit a Page tab with your application you can check if he is connected with your application by comparing Page ID with User ID in signed_requests, for unauthorized users ID's will be same. In that case you can start authentication flow by redirecting user's browser to "login url".

If you want it to be full page just do the redirect with JavaScript like this:

```
window.top.location = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
 client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=COMA_SEPARATED_PERMISSIONS'
```

If you using PHP you can construct Login URL by calling `Facebook->getLoginUrl` method.

Read the docs on [Facebook authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)